# Gaming Databases Theory

Tags: android, sqlite, game-development

I'd like some help with data management theory for Android games. I'm developing a role playing game and I'd like the character to be customisable with different outfits: hats, power armour weapons, etc. The player can buy these from a shop and then choose to wear them or change outfit but keep the item in a 'wardrobe ' to wear a different time.

So far, most of my data has been saved via SharedPreferences.  However I know this is unsustainable for 100 different types items the player can buy and then save to wear on a different occasion.

Through research, I am beginning to believe SQLite would be best in Android Studio. Would anyone agree with this or have a better suggestion?

I understand SQLite would allow me to have the data pre-loaded with a 'not bought' status. When 'bought' this status would change and the player could 'wear'  or 'not wear' the clothing.

If SQLite is best, how do I go about it best? Also, does SQLite take a long time to load and therefore slow the opening of an activity down? Could you combine SQLite with SharedPreferences to remember the latest selected outfit?

Finally, is SQLite what other apps use to store data (especially if built through Android Studio)? How do games such as Clash of Clans or Tapped Out save such data as owned items or location on a grid?

Thank you for even partial support or theory.

Comment: `I am beginning to believe SQLite would be best in Android Studio` - please, do not confuse IDE and OS. This would greatly simplify the process of searching for good answers.

Comment: Hi, Dmitry. Let me elaborate a little further: I am working in Android Studio for Android OS wanting to programme a database and querying if SQLite is suitable for my intentions. I hope that helps?

Comment: Realm, Couchbase Lite, or Firebase are other alternatives to look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, SQLite is fine.

**Let me answer this question from Clean Code perspective.**

Answer below could be too complicated for the beginners, but I hope it will be helpful in the long term.

I think your actual question is - how do I save the stuff which I need later on? Well, in most cases it doesn't really matter how you will store the data as long as you can reliably read it back later on. So, instead of worrying about "should I use X?", I would instead start with defining the interface of the class which will solve your problem.

For instance, let's call it `PlayerItemsRepository` and it be responsible for saving your stuff and reading it back. How? I don't know yet, we can figure it out later on.

```
public interface PlayerItemsRepository {

    void saveItems(List<Item> items);

    List<Item> readItems();

}
```

OK, now we can integrate SQLite? Let's wait with that for a little - it's a bit of a boilerplate code to work with SQLite, so how about we will create some simple implementation of this interface which would just serialize the list and save it to file (assuming your `Item` is `Serializable`). Or if we are too lazy even for that, how about we'll just convert our `List<Item>` to JSON and save it to `SharedPreferences` (with something like Gson library which is stupid-simple to use)?

Now, if you're saving just 100 items (which is a rather small amount) I am pretty sure all those "easy" solutions will just work fine and you will be able to just forget about the whole story.

**If** you will start to run into necessity to have some sort of relational model, or performance of serialization is not acceptable to you, or you need a faster and more complicated search mechanics - **then** you might consider switching to SQlite. It is pretty common for Android applications, although (as I mentioned before) API is somewhat cumbersome and requires you to write quite some boilerplate - which is in the end require you to spend more time on it and it might be not worth the time for a small data set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your feedback. I'm investigating JSON option. I think I'm getting to grips with its theory but it'd be great if you've a recommended tutorial or guide? Thanks again.

Comment: For JSON? There is not much teheory behind the format. I would recommend checking the specification and then trying out some popular JSON library (like Gson). As for SQLite - pretty much any book about SQLie + official website for reference. There are lots of materials available online, so it is just a matter of your time investment.